# Setting up sublime text editor for LaTex

Tags: latex, sublime-text

for a few day I have been wondering how to set up sublime text editor for LaTeX editing. I have installed TexLive-full and Latexmk as it has been suggested. Also I have installed sublime text editor. I just don't know how to get Latex into sublime's build menu. Should I somehow make sublime text editor to understand that I'm writing .tex documents and I want them to be compiled to .pdf? There are a few web pages about this thing but I just don't get it. Can someone in a really concrete way to explain how to build .tex documents with sublime text editor. I have understood that I have to do something with LaTextools but I don't even know what that is. Is it something inside the sublime text or something else? The editor opens nicely all my .tex files. And latex is working with other editors. But I would like to use sublime text cause I write long documents and I like to floating image of whole text.

Thank you!

.silouan

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure you have "Package Control" under Preferences. It does make the installation of packages easier. If not, follow the installation process described [here](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation.%20It%20varies%20if%20you%20have%20ST2%20or%20ST3).

Once you've got Package Control, click on it and select "Install Package". Search and install "LaTeXTools".

Finally, under Preferences/Package Settings you should now have LaTeXTools. Select it and click on Reconfigure "LaTeXTools and migrate settings".

ST should now recognize tex sintax and you should be able to compile tex files with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Is it working now?

Felipe

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.